# Compilation Error when overwriting webapp.dll in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I get the following error when overwriting my asp.net .dll sometimes on my web server. The server is running Windows 2008 and IIS7. The only way I can seem to resolve the issue is to restart IIS7 completely.

**Compilation Error**
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message**: The compiler failed with error code -1073741502.

**Version Information**: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4016; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016

If anyone can help then it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when a third-party component is running in the W3wp.exe process that has attached a console to the process. The Vbc.exe compiler process and the Csc.exe compiler process then inherit this console. If the console uses a windowstation that does not contain a desktop named DEFAULT, this may cause the compiler processes, or any other process that is spawned from the W3wp.exe process that depends on the User32.dll file, not to start.

Comment: What 3rd party component are you using that get referenced in the page request?

Comment: I am not using Visual Basic and when I googled this I got your exact response. This problem was linked to VB. I am not debugging or anything, literally overwriting the file. And Im not using any 3rd party components I don't think ...